# How to assign grabbed data to outer scope variable in JavaScript restangular

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, restangular, scopes

I'm were had troble to fetching plain objects from database using restangular and i solved it by using restangular plain() method on fetched data. but now i'm having a trouble on assigning that data to outer scope variable. demo code-

i have load all function -

```
function loadAll() {

var feelings = [];

Restangular.all('feelings').getList().then(function(data) {

    angular.forEach(data.plain(), function(feeling) {
        feelings.push(feeling);
    })

})

console.log(feelings) // shows empty array :( , how to sole this issue

//----------------------------------------

// i wants my data like this to be returned

var feelings = [{
    feeling_name: 'best',
    view_count: 50
}, {
    feeling_name: 'funny',
    view_count: 150
}, {
    feeling_name: 'angry',
    view_count: 40
}, {
    feeling_name: 'loved',
    view_count: 42
}]


//-----------------------------------------------

return feelings.map(function(feeling) {
    feeling.value = feeling.feeling_name.toLowerCase();
    return feeling;
});

}
```